# Dynamically create object of DLLs form Factory - C++

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-loading

Hi have 6 projects defined in my IDE.

1. EventHelper
2. ConfigParser
3. OfficeEventHandler
4. Messaging
5. LoggingAndPersistence
6. ScreenCamera

**EventHelper** has the entry point. The rest of the projects are the DLL which gets absorbed by the **EventHelper**.

**Messaging** and **ConfigParser** is being used in every other DLLs as well. So the code for loading the DLLs and acessing it is common in all the modules (Code Redundancy).

```
dllHandle_parser = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT("ConfigParser.dll"));

if (!dllHandle_parser){
    return;
}

configParserClient_fctry = reinterpret_cast<configParser>(::GetProcAddress(dllHandle_parser, "getParserInstance"));

if (!configParserClient_fctry) {
    ::FreeLibrary(dllHandle_parser);
    return;
}

parser = configParserClient_fctry();
```

And the similar code for **Messaging**

My question is
Is there a way where I can have one DLL called **ObjectFactory** where I can give the name of the class (in runtime, in string format) whose to be created. Something like
`ObjectFactory.getInstance("ConfigParser/Messaging")`. (Java like `Class.forName("className")`)

Or if not possible this way, what would be the suggested architecture?

Comment: Why load the DLLs through code instead of linking with their export libraries?

Comment: Regarding your question, no you can't use strings to get classes at runtime, as C++ doesn't have [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) (which Java does). But you can a pre-made (created at compile time) list of names, and have a function search through that list for a factory function or object to create the specified object instance.